# How to reference a PDF document found on a website

Tags: publications, citations

I want to use this website in my report but I do not see the produced year of the following pdf `https://www.astm.org/BOOKSTORE/DS68/pg41.pdf`

How can I do the reference of that pdf ?

Is this correct : `ASTM international, "Ultrasonic Testing," ASTM international,. [Online]. Available: https://www.astm.org/BOOKSTORE/DS68/pg41.pdf. [Accessed September 2016].`

Comment: Flagged as unclear because you don't say what citation style you're using

Comment: You should direct this questions to the institution/publisher you are producing work for.  They will have variations in their house styles.  Also, university and library resources, as well as Google, will tell you how to generally reference websites.

Comment: I want to use some of the values in the second table in the website ..

Comment: As I explained in my answer below, asking about wanting to cite a website URL and asking about wanting to cite a PDF are two different questions. There is therefore no duplication.

Comment: Hi .. if I want to copy a text from this site : https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Ultrasonics/EquipmentTrans/piezotransducers.htm ... Is it ok if I write like this : according to NDT resource center '' The thickness of the active element is determined by the desired frequency of the transducer ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a book, you will probably be asked to give the book citation instead of the link. In this case you reference the book as indicated by the journal and refer to the page inline.

e.g. We used the water attenuation as a function of frequency from Book_Author, year (Table 2.7, p. 41).

In the references use the journal's style, or for your report, use the style you reference papers. Then use the publisher of the book instead of the journal name (e.g. Cambridge University press)

This is usually done because a link might be broken after some years and then the reader won't be able to find the reference. In science, links are usually used when referring to some online extra material (e.g. videos, tables, codes, datasets) that the authors uploads to their own webpages, besides the online material provided to the journal. This is usually done because they want the data to be publicly available and the online material on the journal webpage might not be.

Even if your question is about a report and not a scientific journal, the best way to approach this is to learn to proper way to do it and stick to it. This will make your texts more professional and when it comes to papers you will be less likely to have cited, captioned etc something in the wrong way. The latter will help you have shorter referee report with less corrections.

Comment: Hi .. if I want to copy a text from this site : nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Ultrasonics/… ... Is it ok if I write like this : according to NDT resource center '' The thickness of the active element is determined by the desired frequency of the transducer ''

Comment: Well it depends on how well know is the webpage in your field. If everybody refer to it then ok. If you are the first person to do so, no. Imagine how "according to wikipedia" would sound. On the other hand, "according to scholarpedia", which is peer reviewed, might be unusual but I assume you wouldn't have troubles.  Still, usually there is a textbook you can find to reference for generic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Disambiguation needed here: a PDF is not a website.

The PDF is an image, or a representation, of the published text.

That image is not what the editor nor the reader are interested in.

The source should quote the original instance of publication of that text, be it electronically or between covers.

If the PDF is the image of a published document, then the citation will be able the published document, regardless of whether that document was consulted in its hard copy version or as an electronic PDF version.

Comment: Hi .. if I want to copy a text from this site : nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Ultrasonics/… ... Is it ok if I write like this : according to NDT resource center '' The thickness of the active element is determined by the desired frequency of the transducer ''

Comment: Is the quote an original unique statement that was authored by whoever is responsible for the publication of that website? If not, expectation would be that you go up to the original source of the statement (Seems to be a typical Wikipedia situation.)

Comment: yes  it is an original unique statement that was authored by website

Comment: Best option is then to follow the styling guidelines you've decided upon, Harvard, or else, or the use of the publication you're contributing to. Citing websites is nothing new so there is a track record of best - and not so good - practices to cite websites.